# Правильный вывод json

Tags: javascript, json

Помогите сделать правильный вывод json данных

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                function UpdateBlocks(){
                    var url = "http://exemple.com/test.php"; // {"time":"2017-08-26 11:09:21","current":1444444,"average":1375930}
                    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }); 
                }
                UpdateBlocks();
                setInterval(UpdateBlocks, 5000);
    });
```

На выходе

```
        Object{ time: "2017-08-26 11:29:20", current: 1666666, average: 1423087 }
        Object{ time: "2017-08-26 11:29:24", current: 1666666, average: 1421889 }
        Object{ time: "2017-08-26 11:29:29", current: 1666666, average: 1421224 }
        Object{ time: "2017-08-26 11:29:34", current: 1666666, average: 1421224 }
        Object{ time: "2017-08-26 11:29:39", current: 1666666, average: 1420560 }
```

Требуется так чтобы после каждого запроса добавлялась новая строка в объект

```
Object[
        Object{ time: "2017-08-26 11:29:20", current: 1666666, average: 1423087 },
        Object{ time: "2017-08-26 11:29:24", current: 1666666, average: 1421889 },
        Object{ time: "2017-08-26 11:29:29", current: 1666666, average: 1421224 },
        Object{ time: "2017-08-26 11:29:34", current: 1666666, average: 1421224 },
        Object{ time: "2017-08-26 11:29:39", current: 1666666, average: 1420560 }
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не уверен что понял вопрос, но возможно как-то так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let blocksData = [];

  function UpdateBlocks(){
    var url = "http://exemple.com/test.php"; // {"time":"2017-08-26 11:09:21","current":1444444,"average":1375930}
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      blocksData.push(data)
      console.log(blocksData);
    }); 
  }
  UpdateBlocks();
  setInterval(UpdateBlocks, 5000);
});
```